# How to debug Play 2 unit test for server side

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have an unit test like this:

```
    @Test
    public void callRegisterByForm() {
//  AnyContentAsJson anyContentAsJson = null;
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("phoneNumber", "+5103978860");
                map.put("countryCode", "us");

                Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest("POST", "/register").withFormUrlEncodedBody(map));
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
                assertThat(contentType(result)).isEqualTo("application/json");
                JsonNode jsonResult = Json.parse(contentAsString(result));
                assertThat(jsonResult.get(Config.DEV_REG_STATUS_PARAM).asText()).isEqualTo("OK");
                assertThat(jsonResult.get(Config.DEV_PHONE_NUMBER_PARAM).asText()).isEqualTo("+5103978860");
            }
        });

    }
```

How do I test the server's controller? I tried to setup a remote java application and use 'play debug run' on console but still not able **right click on this test case to run** and **have the server's controller stop at breakpoints**.

This is the image when I right click a test case. It asks me to select a launcher to use.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMMh since I'm using the TypeSafe stack I don't have access to the `play` executable.

However, I know a way to start the play server in debug mode.
Actually I wrote it on my blog [here](http://ska-la.blogspot.be/2012/03/typesafe-stack-20-missing-play-debug.html).

```
`export SBT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999`
```

will do the trick to have the JVM (running your Play server) listening for one debug connection.

After what, you've said it, you setup a remote application that connect to `localhost:9999`

In the play console, you'll have the option to

- launch `test` and debug (in case you've unit test for your controller)
- test your app by hand (otherwise)

**EDIT**

Related to running the test in eclipse, I cannot see how to do since it relies on the classpath and probably some configuration.

However what could be done is to execute `play debug test-only test.accounts.MyTest`, assuming you've a test called `MyTest` in the test classpath under the package `test.accounts`. This will execute only the MyTests's tests.

While starting attach you debugger (remote app) to the jvm in order the walk the code.

Another way might be :
* `play debug` in one console, 
* attach the debugger
* open an another console to execute `test-only test.accounts.MyTest` as many times as you want.

Comment: What is this different from 'play debug run'? For 'play debug run', I already able to launch a local server and have Eclipse to connect to 9999 port for remote debugging.

Comment: How ok, it wasn't clear to me... sorry. Hum for your problem, you might (maybe) look at how to debug specs2 test in eclipse ?

Comment: Yes for sure, but what type of test did you created ?

Comment: Just like the example I posted. It is using Play 2 fakeApplication(). http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTest

Comment: Well well... Actually I'll have to read à bit what does 'test' to help you. Do some look in the svt command will be necessart....

Comment: Hey man, is the last EDIT I did would be ok for you ? It's like a workaround to what you want to do...

Comment: Yes, it works. First, 'play debug' in one console. Attach eclipse to listen to localhost:9999. Then run 'test-only mytest'.