# Play! Framework 2.2.0 : impossible to debug in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, testing, playframework

I'm trying to debug my unit tests with Eclipse (Kepler), in a Play! project.
I launched **play debug**. In Eclipse, I created a Remote Java Application in Debug Configurations with the port supplied by the output of the command line. Clicked Apply, then Debug, added breakpoints. In the command prompt of my Play project, I launched **test**.
Eclipse never stops at the breakpoints. It's very annoying. I'm on Windows 7 Pro 64bits.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
   // Add your own project settings here
   Keys.fork in (Test) := false
)
```

in your Build.scala as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201034/how-to-debug-tests-with-play-2-0)

With command line in your Play! project:

- play clean
- play compile
- play debug
- (in eclipse) run your debug remote
- test

I just test it in Keppler, works fine for me ;)

Comment: Thanks, it helped. As I work with Play! 2.2.x, I modified build.sbt, I entered `Keys.fork in Test := false`.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Pierre-Yves' suggestion (I'm new to Play 2.2 and SBT, so this may be avoidable), to debug individual unit tests via IntelliJ I needed the following in build.sbt (thanks to [Mike Slinn](http://mikeslinn.blogspot.com/2013/09/sample-play-22x-buildsbt.html)):

```
Keys.fork in Test := false

parallelExecution in Test := false
```

Without the build.sbt changes, executing the following in the Play debug console (each session) worked:

```
$ set sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false
```

After either of those solutions, I could then set breakpoints and remote debug individual test classes via:

```
$ test-only *package.class*
```

Comment: Had the same issue in play 2.2.6. Fixed by adding those two lines in the end of `build.sbt `

Comment: This solution solved a similar issue I was having with IntelliJ IDEA 14