# Play Framework 2.1 debug subproject unit tests with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, debugging, playframework, remote-debugging

No problems debugging my Play webapp with eclipse debugger, but have been unsuccessful in getting the debugger to engage during unit tests.  I have tried the suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201034/how-to-debug-tests-with-play-2-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398500/play-framework-2-2-0-impossible-to-debug-in-eclipse) but when I connect my debugger through Eclipse, my break points are still getting ignored.

My webapp consists of two **subprojects** and I have added the setting:

```
Keys.fork in (Test) := false
```

to all three **Build.scala** files in the play.Project(...).settings section: both of my subprojects as well as the one the one at the top level.  I then do the following:

1. from the play console, run **play clean**
2. from the play console, run **play compile**
3. from the play console, run **play debug**
4. from Eclipse, run debug configuration looking at port 9999 (same one I use to debug webapp successfully)
5. at the play $ prompt, run **test**

Are there additional steps to take when debugging tests that part of a **subproject** or if using **fakeApplication** (I'm doing model testing with an in-memory db)?

Answer (score 0):

In the top level **build.scala** file there were three lines that looked like this:

```
val proj1 = play.Project(appName + "-Proj1", appVersion, proj1Dependencies, path = file("subprojects/Proj1") )

val proj2 = play.Project(appName + "-Proj2", appVersion, proj2Dependencies, path = file("subprojects/Proj2") )

val main = play.Project(appName,      appVersion, mainDependencies).settings(
// Add your own project settings here)
).dependsOn( proj1, proj2 ).aggregate( proj1, proj2 )
```

I was wanting to debug unit tests in proj2, so I needed to add the new setting there like so:

```
val proj2 = play.Project(appName + "-Proj2", appVersion, proj2Dependencies, path = file("subprojects/Proj2") ).settings(
Keys.fork in (Test) := false
```

)

Note: In this example, all three dependency variables: mainDependencies, proj1Dependencies, and proj2Dependencies point to the same base dependencies that look like this:

```
val baseDependencies = Seq(
javaCore,
javaJdbc,
javaEbean,
"xom" % "xom" % "1.2.5",
"net.sf.json-lib" % "json-lib" % "2.4" classifier "jdk15"
```

)